# BlockingResponse in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm attempting to redirect a user in a Firefox extension like so:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  ({ url }) => {
    const [fullMatch, type, identifier] =
      url.match(
        /open\.spotify\.com\/(track|album|artist|playlist|concert|episode|show|user)\/([^\&\#\/\?]+)/i
      ) || [];

    return { redirectUrl: `spotify:${type}:${identifier}` };
  },
  {
    urls: ["*://open.spotify.com/track/*", "*://open.spotify.com/album/*",
  "*://open.spotify.com/artist/*", "*://open.spotify.com/playlist/*",
  "*://open.spotify.com/concert/*", "*://open.spotify.com/episode/*",
  "*://open.spotify.com/show/*", "*://open.spotify.com/user/*"],
    types: ["xmlhttprequest"],
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

I've added webRequest and webRequestBlocking permissions in the manifest. In the debugger, I see that I am reaching the return statement with the redirectUrl correctly set, but the webpage does not redirect. I would assume this should redirect based upon the [webRequest documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest), however the temporary extension does not seem to redirect. Any ideas on how to get the extension to redirect? Changing the url to https://www.google.com, for example, doesn't work either, so it seems the issue is not with the URL.

Comment: `redirectUrl` must be a proper URL while `spotify:${type}:${identifier}` doesnt appear to be.

Comment: changing the URL to https://www.google.com doesn't work either, I've updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I've determined the issue is with the *types* array. xmlhttprequest does not capture certain requests in Firefox, but does in Chrome. In order to still be able to redirect, the types should be as follows:

```
  types: [
  "main_frame",
  "xmlhttprequest"]
```